# Creating a search app like EasyFind

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, search

On OS X there is a popular app called EasyFind that searches for strings inside of a files content or you can just do a name search. More importantly, it searches in hidden files and inside of package contents.

So my research with using the Spotlight API leads me to believe that it is not possible to do this. Should I assume EasyFind is doing this all manually without using any Cocoa search API?

If that is true, does anyone know of some code to get me started, even just pseudo?

Basically I want to build an app that will find every single image on the drive no matter where it is or what permissions it has. This also includes icon files.

One other thing I can't seem to find an answer to is whether or not you can do a search like this on the command line in OS X.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the command line you can use the [`find`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/blcmdl1_findx.htm) command line tool. That gives you access to all the files in the filesystem if you run it with root permissions (`sudo`). You can pipe its results to `grep` to find for strings inside the files. You can also use the `strings` command line tool to look for strings inside binary files.

---

This is not very complicated to implement within a Cocoa App. Just Google for how to iterate through all the hard drive contents. [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) could be a good place to start digging.

---

Also check out [FindAnyFile](http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/). It is a nice app that does similar to EasyFind but just on file properties (name, dates, etc.). It doesn't read file contents.

Comment: Yep I actually loaded EasyFind into a hex editor and saw they are doing everything through NSFileMananger. Thanks!

Comment: @DeltaGroup: Easier ways include `nm` and `class-dump`.